# how do i get data from a DAO arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, dao

I am trying to create a method to read data from my DAO arraylist class. i want the data of the current indexpossition to be shown in some textfields. 
My problem is that i dont know how to create my method to get the data from my DAO arraylist class.
i am swedish btw that's the reasons for the wied method names.

```
private void visaBil() {

    DTOBil[] bilar = dao.getAllDTOBil();

    for(DTOBil bil : bilar){
        text1.setText(bil.get(index).regnr);
        text2.setText(bil.get(index).marke);
        text3.setText(bil.get(index).modell);
        text4.setText(bil.get(index).sokVag);

        String source = text4.getText();

        try {

            jlBilder.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(source)));

        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {}
    }
}
```

my DAOArarylist class (not all of it)

```
public class DAOBilArrayList implements DAOBil{
private ArrayList<DTOBil> dtoBilar;



public DAOBilArrayList(){

    dtoBilar = new ArrayList<DTOBil>();

    dtoBilar.add(new DTOBil("ABC123", "Citroen", "C4", "http://www.carsuk.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Citroen-C4-Aircross-100x100.jpg"));
    dtoBilar.add(new DTOBil("DEF456", "Audi", "RS4", "http://www.carsuk.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Audi-RS4-Avant-2013-Spy-Video-100x100.jpg"));
    dtoBilar.add(new DTOBil("GHH123", "BMW", "730Ld", "http://www.carsuk.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/BMW-730Ld-Chauffeur-100x100.jpg"));

}



@Override
public void create(DTOBil dtobil) {
    dtoBilar.add(dtobil);
}    

@Override
public DTOBil[] getAllDTOBil() {
    return dtoBilar.toArray(new DTOBil[dtoBilar.size()]);
}
```

what do i do to get my visabil method to get the data from my DAO class?

Comment: Not sure what `DTOBil` is (guessing that is a class you made?), but should `text1.setText(bil.get(index).regnr);` be something like `text1.setText(bil.getRegnr());`? That is what I would have expected without knowing what `DTOBil` is anyway...

Comment: I don't see the point in creating a new array in the `getAllDTOBil` method. Try changing the body of this method with `return dtoBilar();`. Then instead of using DTOBil[], use List<DTOBil>

Comment: but then how will i know what indexpossition from the arraylist it will print out to the textfields?

in my program i have butting that make me able to go through all of the items in the arraylist. a forward and backwards buttong if you know what i mean. that's why i wanted to know the indexpossition

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem.

When using `for(DTOBil bil : bilar) {}`, you don't need an index variable. `bil` is already pointing to one element of your array and will increment on its own.

Try using `bil.regnr` or even `bil.getRegnr()`, like Windle said.